# MediaRecorder iOS 14.6: mimeType not supported

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, web-mediarecorder

I am recording and sending audio via a website. For that purpose I use the MediaRecorder API.

There are no issues when using the site on desktop or Android devices and according to the [MediaRecorder documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder), since a release in September 2020, iOS 14 should be supported as well.

The MediaRecorder is instantiated like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
  .then((stream) => {
    // Some validation and other processing. Omitted for brevity.

    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });

    // Using the mediaRecorder. Omitted for brevity.
  });
```

When doing this on an iPhone 12 with iOS 14.6, i get the following error from that instantiation line:

```
NotSupportedError: mimeType is not supported
```

I get the same error when trying other formats (these are the ones I found and tried):

- `audio/webm` (as shown in example above)
- `video/webm`
- `audio/ogg` (also errors on desktop)
- `audio/ogg; codecs=opus` (also errors on desktop)

Is there any mimeType for MediaRecorder that lets me use audio on iOS devices?

Am I getting something else entirely wrong?

Comment: Hi Felix, I'm using Ionic React and using React-Webcam. I also chose the mimeType: video/mp4, and it led to the "mimeType not supported" error. Are you using Ionic as well? If so, did you find a way to get the camera working on iOS simulator?

Comment: btw, which `mime-type` is supported by `MediaRecorder` can be live tested using https://www.sitelint.com/lab/media-recoder-supported-mime-type/

Answer (score 5):

A preferred solution for me is something like this:

```
if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs=vp9')) {
    var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'};
} else  if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm')) {
    var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
} else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4')) {
    var options = {mimeType: 'video/mp4', videoBitsPerSecond : 100000};
} else {
    console.error("no suitable mimetype found for this device");
}
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

IOS only allows mp4, so after running this code you will get that option automatically.
I believe this is probably a better method than a try catch for the error.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out `video/mp4` works with iOS. It can be used for audio-only as well, even though it says video.

Since other browsers don't support `video/mp4`, a try/catch with the `video/mp4` as a fallback can be used, which results in the following solution:

```
let mediaRecorder;
try {
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });
}
catch (err1) {
  try {
    // Fallback for iOS
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/mp4' });
  }
  catch (err2) {
    // If fallback doesn't work either. Log / process errors.
    console.error({err1});
    console.error({err2})
  }
}
```

The code could be made cleaner and more explicit by:

- catching the `NotSupportedError` explicitly
- querying the device / OS and using the according mimeType explicitly, instead of knowingly running into an error.

But for now it works and that's good enough for a personal project.

Comment: video/mp4 results in a 1 second audio when recorded on Chrome-iOS. Is this something you ran across during your issue, i have already spent a lot of time on this on getting audio recording to work on Chrome/iOS, any help is appreciated!

Comment: @arjary No, using the code above I don't encounter your problem with Chrome on iOS w\ iPhone 12, iOS 14.6.
The `start` function of MediaRecorder has an optional parameter `timeslice`, if you set this parameter, you get bits of audio of the specified length. I set this to 1000 milliseconds in my project and reassemble the audio later.

Maybe you set the `timeslice` and forgot to reassemble the audio, in that case you would always get a bit of audio of only e.g. 1 second length.

Comment: Or related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70273551/1066234

Answer (score 0):

A more compact answer that uses retries with variable list length

```
const mimeTypes = ["audio/webm", "video/mp4"];

const genericName = async (mimeIndex = 0) => {
    try {
        //Set the mimeType to the first item in the mimeTypes array

        const mimeType = mimeTypes[mimeIndex];
        MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(mimeType);

        //create new Media recorder instance using the stream
        const media: MediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType });


    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log("Error recording", err.message);
        
        // Retry with the next mimeType if the first mimeType fails
        const retries = mimeTypes.length;
        if (mimeIndex < retries) {
        startRecording(mimeIndex + 1);
      }
    }
  };
```