# How to convert AAC/MP4A to MP3 using FFMPEG in full length? Audio file gets cut off after 1 second

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have recorded an audio file with MediaRecorder on iPhone.

As ffmpeg command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i 18380889311644327118 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 18380889311644327118.mp3
```

```
-i specifies the input file
-vn disables all video-streams from the input
-ar audio sampling frequency
-ac number of audio channels
-b:a bit rate
-c:a libmp3lame - codec of target file
-q:a quality set audio quality (codec-specific) (lower is better), see https://superuser.com/a/1515841

-sn disables all subtitle-streams from the input
-dn disables all data-streams from the input
```

The console output looks like this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '18380889311644327118':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    creation_time   : 2021-12-08T15:44:06.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2258 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 2234 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-08T15:44:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))

Output #0, mp3, to '18380889311644327118.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    TSSE            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-12-08T15:44:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libmp3lame
size=      17kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate= 135.5kbits/s speed=37.2x
video:0kB audio:16kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.343701%
```

As you can see, the duration is `01.00` second. And this happens with all recorded files.

How to convert the entire file (which is 12 seconds long) to its full length?

Note: It seems that the recorded file does not have a length specified. Under Windows I renamed the file, adding an extension ".m4a" and opened the file properties:

[image: m4a properties]

The length attribute is empty.

Comment: Works fine here with the sample. Upgrade to ffmpeg 4.4 and check.

Comment: On my server therer is `ffmpeg 4.2.4`. When I run `apt install ffmpeg` it says `ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1).`. How to upgrade to version 4.4 on the command line? – The [ffmpeg download page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg) states "7:4.4.1-2ubuntu1" as the latest.

Comment: That is not the ffmpeg download page. This is the download page: http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html   Get a linux static build - git master

Answer (score 1):

As [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) wrote, the conversion works with `ffmpeg v4.4` which does not come with the recent Ubuntu update.

However, you can install it customly, see instructions here:

[Safest way to install latest stable ffmpeg (>= 4.3) on Ubuntu 20.04 (ppa not working)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1360827/238253)

Then the conversion from `audio/mp4` (codec AAC) to `mp3` works.